# Detecting break point in Sentinel-2 time series

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2, time-series, datetime

I am trying to create a simple method for wildfire detection using Sentinel-2 time series via GEE. The method is based on the decrease of the Normalized Burned Area (NBR) Index when a fire occurs.

So far I managed to pre-process my Sentinel-2 time series successfully. I filtered the image collection by date, ROI and tile; calculated the NBR; masked the clouds and; applied linear interpolation to fill in the gaps. Script here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/4d1b76549b23c72b160886882ef32dd7

At this moment I have an imageCollection with 22 NBR images. As you can see in the chart below there is a break point in August 2022 when the wildfire occurred. My goal now is to be able to automatically detect at what time the break point is. I consider a break point to be a decrease of NBR >= 0.3.

[image]

How could I do this? Maybe the CCDC algorithm can be an option but I don't know how to implement it properly with `ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.Ccdc`.

Comment: The relevant information is contained in the delta. Considering this you could greatly simplify your problem by representing the metric as a series if pair-wise deltas (ie., t2 = t2 - t1, t3 = t3 -  t2, ...) finding a threshold and then identifying the point in time where the threshold is exceeded. This would provide a more stable and justifiable result than a temporal breakpoint on single-date measures of NBR.

Comment: This would be a perfect solution for me. But, I don't know how to implement it in GEE yet. I'm working on it. I supose I should use `.itetate()` or `.map()` over the image collection.